# ThreeJS Object not loading when using materials

Tags: three.js

I am starting to learn this awesome library and I am totally in love. I followed a couple of tutorials and managed to import my 3d model (obj extension) just fine.

But when I want to import the .mtl file as well, nothing happens just a black screen.

Could anyone please explain me what I am doing wrong?

working code (without materials):

```
loader.load(
    'scene.obj',
    function ( object ) {
        scene.add( object );
    },
    function ( xhr ) {
        console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
    },
    function ( error ) {
        console.log( 'An error happened' );
    }
);
```

Code that is not working:

```
let materialLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
materialLoader.load('scene.mtl', function(materials){

    materials.preload();

    let objectLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objectLoader.setMaterials(materials);

    objectLoader.load('scene.obj', function(mesh){
        scene.add(mesh);
    });

});
```

Unfortunately, I do not receive any errors or warnings in my developers console, and thus I have no clue where to look.

I hope someone can help me out with this matter.

Best regards

P.S. Link to my code: http://159.69.213.164/3d/

Comment: have you set your camera's z far enough? some times you set your camera not far enough then it stands inside the model and causes the black screen

Comment: yeah, when I use the "working" code it works perfect but without textures :) it just doesnt work (cant see anything)  with the code that does load a texture.

Comment: i think you should add some camera control to look around and check if your model loaded, and also change the color of the renderer to something else other than black for it might make you confused with your non-material black object

Comment: Just found out whats happening. No clue why and how to solve it though. But when I change the background (black) to white, I can see my model loaded, but no textures. The model is just black :(

I exported with 3ds Max 2018, both OBJ and MTL files are there.

Comment: there you go. i'm having the same issue with the texture, no solution so far

Comment: yeah, kinda lack of information here. Did u try the same as me lol? making the background white? maybe its there but the same color hahaha.

Comment: I've set it to white right at the first place